# AWS ALB and Autoscaling Groups: cyclic dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to create an AWS Autoscaling Group that is fronted by an Application Load Balancer (ALB).

So I begin by creating the Autoscaling Group and after a few screens it allows me to select whether or not I want an ALB. If I select ALB, then it presents me the UI for creating an ALB. The problem is when you get to selecting the Target Group, which is not optional.

My *understanding* of the Target Group is the pool of resources to forward traffic onto. So in this case, it would be the Autoscaling Group.

So its a Catch-22 here. You can't create the ALB without the Target Group (the Autoscaling Group). And you can't create an ALB-fronted Autoscaling Group without the ALB. **So what's the solution here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Create a target group
2. Create an ALB
3. Create the ASG

Comment: What resources is the target group pointing to?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup No resources at the beginning. Just empty TG. Later ASG will be adding resources to it.